# Webpack + Angular(4) + ES6 on IE11 not working

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've been investigating quite a bit this issue and honestly I don't know what to try next. For some reason my webpack is not able to be executed in IE11 (the only IE I've tried), Safari on iPads with iOS 9.3.5 and some Android phones. I'm not sure if they all have the same issue but here I show the IE one. The actual error I'm getting is SCRIPT1002: Syntax error:

```
    "use strict";
eval("\r\nvar __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {\r\n    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;\r\n    if (typeof Reflect === \"object\" && typeof Reflect.decorate === \"function\") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);\r\n    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;\r\n    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;\r\n};\r\nObject.defineProperty(exports, \"__esModule\", { value: true });\r\nconst core_1 = __webpack_require__(38);\r\nconst platform_browser_1 = __webpack_require__(92);\r\nconst app_component_1 = __webpack_require__(714);\r\nlet AppModule = class AppModule {\r\n};\r\nAppModule = __decorate([\r\n    core_1.NgModule({\r\n        bootstrap: [\r\n            app_component_1.AppComponent,\r\n        ],\r\n        declarations: [\r\n            app_component_1.AppComponent,\r\n        ],\r\n        imports: [\r\n            platform_browser_1.BrowserModule,\r\n        ],\r\n    })\r\n], AppModule);\r\nexports.AppModule = AppModule;\r\n//# sourceURL=[module]\n//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,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\n//# sourceURL=webpack-internal:///713\n");
```

Now, I've been playing around with several polyfills.ts, adding different packages and imports such as the ones suggested in the tour of heroes https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-tour-of-heroes/blob/master/src/polyfills.ts however that doesn't seem to work. I'm starting to believe it's a webpack issue but again, I may be missing something here. I reproduced the error on a simple app with just the app-component:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

The app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and this works fine on Chrome, FF and Safari on the iPhones (iOS 10+ . I know some people didn't experience the issue on older versions of iOS but like I say, I'm a bit lost here and not sure how that's possible).

My packages.json is quite simple and took the latest of the packages to get this up and running quickly:

```
{
  "name": "my-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Website",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 10209",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.3.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.3.5",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "mdn-polyfills": "5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.3",
    "babel-minify": "0.2.0",
    "css-loader": "0.28.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "tslint": "5.6.0",
    "tslint-loader": "3.5.3",
    "typescript": "2.4.2",
    "typings": "2.1.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.5.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.7.1",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0"
  }
}
```

The webpack configuration is, again quite straightforward. webpack.common.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const helpers = require('./helpers.js');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },

  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.ts$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        loader: 'tslint-loader',
        options: {
          emitErrors: true,
          tsConfigFile: 'tsConfig.json',
          configFile: 'tslint.json',
          failOnHint: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: [{
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            options: {
              configFileName: 'tsconfig.json'
            }
          },
          'angular2-template-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/images/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader'
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        use: [{
          loader: 'raw-loader'
        }]
      },
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
    }),

    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
      helpers.root('../src')
    )
  ]
};
```

and the webpack.dev.js:

```
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:10209/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
  }
});
```

My vendor.ts is very standard:

```
// Angular
import "@angular/common";
import "@angular/core";
import "@angular/platform-browser";
import "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import "@angular/router";

// RxJS
import "rxjs";
```

and so is the main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import { AppModule } from "./app/app.module";

if (process.env.ENV === "production") {
    enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

The polyfills.ts I'm currently using:

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/* IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import "core-js/es6/symbol";
// tslint:disable-next-line:ordered-imports
import "core-js/es6/object";
import "core-js/es6/function";
import "core-js/es6/parse-int";
// tslint:disable-next-line:ordered-imports
import "core-js/es6/parse-float";
import "core-js/es6/number";
// tslint:disable-next-line:ordered-imports
import "core-js/es6/math";
import "core-js/es6/string";
// tslint:disable-next-line:ordered-imports
import "core-js/es6/date";
import "core-js/es6/array";
import "core-js/es6/regexp";
// tslint:disable-next-line:ordered-imports
import "core-js/es6/map";
import "core-js/es6/set";
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// tslint:disable-next-line:align
// tslint:disable-next-line:ordered-imports
import "classlist.js";  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/* Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import "core-js/es6/reflect";
import "core-js/es7/reflect";

/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/animation`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 */
// tslint:disable-next-line:align
import "web-animations-js";  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
 */
import "zone.js/dist/zone"; // Included with Angular CLI.

/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */

/**
 * Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
 */
// tslint:disable-next-line:align
import "intl";  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
/**
 * Need to import at least one locale-data with intl.
 */
// tslint:disable-next-line:align
import "intl/locale-data/jsonp/en";
```

And finally the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script>
        document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <title>My website</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <my-app>
    </my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

The tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    "exclude":[
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Now my question is: Is it possible to run and webpack'ed app targeting ES6 on IE11 and some of the other browsers? I have already searched quite a bit but unfortunately I haven't come across a working solution for this. I guess if I was able to "debug" webpack and see why that's failing I could perhaps get a better understanding of the actual problem but I don't know how to do that and whether I can do that against any browser.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Carlos, did you manage to fix the issue? I have the same with Angular 8

Comment: Hi! I do target es5 but I haven’t tried recently another target. Maybe it does work now but I’m not sure. All I can tell is that es5 + Angular 7 works

Comment: Lucky you. es5 + Angular 8 doesn't work :)
Maybe that is related to some another package, I'm trying to figure that out.

Comment: @Aviw Have you got this to work? I'm now getting the same issue in one of our Angular 8 projects.

Comment: @PatrickMcElreavy As far as I remember - yes, but I don't remember for sure what was the root cause. Try targets "es5" and "es2015". If will not work, write me in fb (AviwX3) on Monday, have no time now, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have to add this code to your polyfills.ts

```
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Check that have you added all. It will be helpful in most cases. In my project in angular2, I had to add

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
```

to index.html. In Angular4, this problem should be solved but you can try it.

Comment: @CarlosTorrecillas I edited my answer. Maybe it will be helpful

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I keep having the exact same result